# How do I list the mounts of all namespaces?

Tags: linux, containers

Linux namespaces allow one to have different mounts for different namespaces. How can I list all mounts of all namespaces?

I have found /proc/*/ns/mnt, but I am not sure what to do with those.

Answer (score 7):

`tail -n +1 -- /proc/*/mounts` is per process, but it gets the job done

Answer (score 3):

You can list all the mount namespaces (constraining the output by `-o PID` to only display process IDs; using raw output with `-r`; and skipping header with `-n`) and then show the contents of `/proc/$PID/mounts` for each namespace:

```
for PID in $(lsns -t mnt -o PID -r -n); do
    ps u $PID
    cat /proc/$PID/mounts
done
```